# Pyparsing DOT record label (recursion)

Tags: pyparsing

I am trying to use pyparsing to parse the label used for DOT records. The syntax is:

```
rlabel → '{' ﬁeld ( '|' ﬁeld )* '}'
ﬁeld → boxLabel | rlabel
boxLabel → [ ’<’ string ’>’ ] [ string ]
```

I have two issues. One, I am not sure how to handle boxLabel because it has to optionals. Two, I think I have a left recursion but since there is no "operator" not sure how to deal with it. 
What I've done so far:

```
langle = pyparsing.Literal('<')
rangle = pyparsing.Literal('>')
string = pyparsing.Word('alphanums')
port_id = pyparsing.Group(langle + string + rangle)
port_name = pyparsing.Group(string)
box_label = pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.Optional(port_id) + pyparsing.Optional(port_name))
rlabel = pyparsing.Forward()
field = box_label | rlabel
rlabel_content = pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(field + "|") + field
rlabel << pyparsing.nestedExpr(opener='{', content=rlabel_content, closer='}')
```

Parsing goes into infinite recursion.

Further,

```
>> print(box_label.parseString("<h> root"))
[[['<', 'h', '>']]]
```

and I have no idea why the *port_name* parsing is not present in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats on making this much progress on your pyparsing project, recursive grammars are tricky to get your head around the first time you do them.

First, a minor typo, but one which is probably puzzling you in that it creates a valid parser, but a strangely limited one.

```
string = pyparsing.Word('alphanums')
```

should be

```
string = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums)
```

When you pass a string to `Word`, that defines the list of valid characters to use when parsing such a character group.  So `Word("0123456789")` will parse an integer, `Word("AB")` will parse any word made up of the letters "A" and "B". `Word('alphanums')` will parse "alpha", "nums", "plums", "haphalump" and many other words, as long as they are made up of the letters in 'alphanums'. I'm pretty sure you want the pyparsing-defined string `pyparsing.alphanums`, which includes the characters 'A'-'Z', 'a'-'z', and '0'-'9'.

Let's tackle the `box_label` question first. In general, you can implement "A and B or just A or just B" as:

```
A + Optional(B) | B
```

Or if you want to be more explicit, you can do:

```
A + B | A | B
```

But this starts to get hairy when you have to work with more than 2 expressions. Fortunately, you only have 2, and I chose the first format for my proposed solution below.

Part of the problem you are having with recursion is that you are using both `Forward` and `nestedExpr` - usually just one or the other is sufficient. But in your case, there is an advantage to using `Forward`, so I'll use that method.

(I've also imported pyparsing as `pp`, to cut down on all the extra chars.)

```
import pyparsing as pp

# suppress these punctuation marks - useful during parsing, but just in the way afterward
langle = pp.Literal('<').suppress()
rangle = pp.Literal('>').suppress()
lbrace = pp.Literal('{').suppress()
rbrace = pp.Literal('}').suppress()

string = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

port_id = langle + string("port_id") + rangle
port_name = string("port_name")

rlabel = pp.Forward()
box_label = pp.Group(port_id + pp.Optional(port_name) | port_name)
field = box_label | rlabel
# use delimitedList(expr) in place of expr + ZeroOrMore(delim + expr)
rlabel <<= pp.Group(lbrace + pp.delimitedList(field, delim='|') + rbrace)
```

Create yourself a set of test strings, and call `runTests` with them to see how your parser behaves:

```
field.runTests("""\
    <h> root
    <h>
    root
    { <h> root | { <h2> sub | <h2>sub2 }}
    { <h> root | { <h2> sub | <h2>sub2 } | sub3 }
""")
```

`runTests` will try to parse each given line, and then either dump the results, or show the parse exception:

```
<h> root
[['h', 'root']]
[0]:
  ['h', 'root']
  - port_id: 'h'
  - port_name: 'root'


<h>
[['h']]
[0]:
  ['h']
  - port_id: 'h'


root
[['root']]
[0]:
  ['root']
  - port_name: 'root'


{ <h> root | { <h2> sub | <h2>sub2 }}
[[['h', 'root'], [['h2', 'sub'], ['h2', 'sub2']]]]
[0]:
  [['h', 'root'], [['h2', 'sub'], ['h2', 'sub2']]]
  [0]:
    ['h', 'root']
    - port_id: 'h'
    - port_name: 'root'
  [1]:
    [['h2', 'sub'], ['h2', 'sub2']]
    [0]:
      ['h2', 'sub']
      - port_id: 'h2'
      - port_name: 'sub'
    [1]:
      ['h2', 'sub2']
      - port_id: 'h2'
      - port_name: 'sub2'


{ <h> root | { <h2> sub | <h2>sub2 } | sub3 }
[[['h', 'root'], [['h2', 'sub'], ['h2', 'sub2']], ['sub3']]]
[0]:
  [['h', 'root'], [['h2', 'sub'], ['h2', 'sub2']], ['sub3']]
  [0]:
    ['h', 'root']
    - port_id: 'h'
    - port_name: 'root'
  [1]:
    [['h2', 'sub'], ['h2', 'sub2']]
    [0]:
      ['h2', 'sub']
      - port_id: 'h2'
      - port_name: 'sub'
    [1]:
      ['h2', 'sub2']
      - port_id: 'h2'
      - port_name: 'sub2'
  [2]:
    ['sub3']
    - port_name: 'sub3'
```

Comment: Thanks! One final thought. For the box_label how can I make it be "A and B or just A or just B or None", which is actually the case of the grammar.

Comment: So you would parse something like this? `{ <h> root | { <h2> sub | <h2>sub2 } |  | sub3 }`  Unfortunately you can't just do `Optional(A) + Optional(B)`, since this could "match" on nothing, and you could either loop infinitely or recurse infinitely in rlabel.  If both are absent, then I think you need to *fail* the current box_label, try rlabel, and then at the end, accept an empty expression. I got this to work by changing `field` to `field = box_label | rlabel | pp.Group(pp.empty)`, so that the above string parses to `[[['h', 'root'], [['h2', 'sub'], ['h2', 'sub2']], [], ['sub3']]]`.